# What am I missing about declaring and accessing a basic cookie with PHP?

Tags: php, apache, cookies

For some reason, I thought this code I had written worked perfectly. Maybe it did - but it does not now.

I am setting a session and a cookie with the same variable like so:

```
session_start();

$id = 1;

// store the session
$_SESSION['mynumber'] = $id;

// store the cookie
setcookie('mynumber', $id);
```

I then refresh the page, where there is the code:

```
echo $_SESSION['mynumber'] . '---' . $_COOKIE['mynumber'];
```

I end up with a result of:

```
1---
```

Why isn't cookie echoing out?

Comment: Read the full docs on `setcookie`. You might want to add additional arguments to your call. The default domain might not be right, or your cookie could be expiring immediately.

Comment: @NicholasPickering I simplified my code for above. In my code my cookie is set with: setcookie('mynumber', $id, time()+215308800, '/', '.thedomainthecookieison.com',true); Wouldn't that mean the cookie isn't going to expire for a long time, and be across the whole domain?

Comment: That code looks good to me... Check to see if there's actually a cookie in your browser for your domain. You can check this differently for each browser. I still bet either the domain is wrong or the cookie has expired. Also, use `var_dump` on the $_COOKIE to make sure its false or NULL. Otherwise, there IS something in it and that something is an empty string.

Comment: Ok cheers. I will see what I can do with that.

Comment: As it's a secure cookie, are you connecting over HTTPS?  (final parameter in your `setcookie` call means the cookie is *only* transmitted over https.)

Comment: @searlea you are right! I misread the documentation and this solves another issue I was having. Thank you heaps!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to put the setcookie() function before the <html> tag.